# Caputo derivative to log Mittag-Leffler function

Tags: summation, special-functions, fractional-calculus, mittag-leffler-function, fractional-differential-equations

Suppose $0<\alpha<1$, I am wondering whether there is a closed form expression to Caputo derivative to log Mittag-Leffler function, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha}\log E_\alpha(x^\alpha)=&\frac{1}{\Gamma[1-\alpha]}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-\alpha}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\log E_\alpha(t^\alpha)\right)dt\\
=&\frac{1}{\Gamma[1-\alpha]}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-\alpha}\frac{1}{E_\alpha(t^\alpha)}\left(\frac{d}{dt}E_\alpha(t^\alpha)\right)dt\\
=&\frac{1}{\Gamma[1-\alpha]}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-\alpha}\frac{1}{E_\alpha(t^\alpha)}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(t^\alpha)^n}{\Gamma[\alpha n+1]}\right)dt\\
=&\frac{1}{\Gamma[1-\alpha]}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-\alpha}\frac{1}{E_\alpha(t^\alpha)}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(t^\alpha)^n}{\Gamma[\alpha n+1]}\right)dt\\
=&\frac{1}{\Gamma[1-\alpha]}\int_0^x(x-t)^{-\alpha}\frac{1}{E_\alpha(t^\alpha)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{t^{\alpha n-1}}{\Gamma[\alpha n]}dt,
\end{align*}
where we may assume $x>0$ to avoid well defined issues. Since there is an infinite summation or a complex integral in the denominator, can we further simplify this integral?

The reason I am asking is that we know the solution to
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=g(x)f(x), \ f(x)\geq 0,
\end{align*}
is
\begin{align*}
f(x)=f(0)\exp{\int_0^xg(s)ds}.
\end{align*}
then what is the solution to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha}f(x)=g(x)f(x), \ f(x)\geq 0,
\end{align*}
I know one special case when $g(x)=1$, then $f(x)=E_\alpha(x^\alpha)$. But do we have a formula for a general $g$?

Any reference or idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I have for you is, after the second line of you initial passages, to introduce the following relationship about the first derivative of the Mittag-Leffler function
$$t^{−(1−α)} E_{α,α} (−t^α) = − \frac{d}{dt} E_α (−t^α)$$
explained by Mainardi at expression 29 of his paper, obviously with the appropriate signs changed in your passages:
Mainardi, F. [Why the Mittag-Leffler Function Can Be Considered the Queen Function of the Fractional Calculus?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7760830/) Entropy (Basel) 2020, 22 (12), 1359. https://doi.org/10.3390/e22121359.